# How do I get rspec / autotest going on a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, autotest

What's the best practice for getting RSpec / Autotest going on a Rails project?

I googled some stuff but it feels like it may be out of date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly [straightforward](https://github.com/rspec/rspec/wiki/autotest) (for Rails3/Bundler):

Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'ZenTest'
  gem 'autotest-rails'
end
```

And then:

```
$ rails generate rspec:install
$ autotest
```

And you're set.